# js execute function after object is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns, require

I need for a function to be executable only after an object is defined, I'm currently working in a fascade pattern and one method is dependent on another method.  in this case 'addNewLayer' fails because 'setFullMap' hasn't finished executing.  is there a solution? I'm using jquery and vanilla js so most any solution would be helpful at this point:

```
var jen = (function(){

  function setFullMap(mapID){
    jen.map = new Map(mapID);
  }

  function setLayer(opt){
   //execute code here after jen.map is defined
  }
 return{
   samp: function(id, opt){
     setFullMap(id);
     addNewLayer(opt);
   }
 };
})();
```

Thanks

**solution:**

```
var jen = (function(){
function setFullMap(mapID, callback) {
    jen.map = new Map(mapID);

    if(jen.map){
      callback();
    }
}

return {
  samp: function(id, opt){
    setFullMap(id, function(){
      addNewLayer(opt);
    }.bind(this));
  }
 };
})();
```

Comment: Can you post/modify the `Map` constructor? If not, then you don't have very many options.

Comment: the Map constructor is apart of an ESRI library, I've had success in adding fields to the constructor

Comment: Is that instantiation of Map deals with DOM repaint/reflow? I mean, does Map work with the DOM?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu yes, the Map will insert images into the DOM at a div "mapID"

Comment: Then, try using a setTimeout with a delay of 0, to let your code catch up with the rendering thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to pass a `callback function` to `setFullMap`, and execute it once the function has completed (at the very end, before the closing `}`).

```
var jen = (function(){

  function setFullMap(mapID, callback){
    jen.map = new Map(mapID);
    callback();
  }

  function setLayer(opt){
   //execute code here after jen.map is defined
  }
 return{
   samp: function(id, opt){
     setFullMap(id, function() {
       addNewLayer(opt);
     }.bind(this));
   }
 };
})();
```

Do not forget using `.bind(this)` - it is very important in order to keep the original `this` in your callback function.

## Edit:

Actually that would not work work if the `Map` constructor is a-synchronous. If you do not have access to the constructor and/or you cannot pass it a callback, then presumably the only (and sad) option would be to use a `setTimeout` or (easier) `setInterval`, continuously checking at defined intervals if the operation has been completed, and then fire the callback.

Comment: I made a small change and the callback did it!...thanks so much

Comment: @atlMapper, It would be good to tell what changes you made, because this answer will probably won't help others having the same issue without additionnal details. Also, have a look at my answer.

Comment: I agree with @plalx, tell us about your modification.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback parameter:

```
function setFullmap(mapId,callback) {
    jen.map = new Map(mapId);
    callback();
}

....

samp: function(id, opt){
    setFullMap(id,function() {
        addNewLayer(opt);
    });
}
```

Comment: This won't actually help, because the asynchronous part of the function is `Map`

Comment: @Kevin B If it's async, how does it return a value?

Comment: If it weren't async then the callback method you mentioned wouldn't be needed. For all we know it could be immediately returning an instance of the class, but then asynchronously setting specific properties of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

When u dont have a way to manipulate the Map Object then u need to use a loop:

```
var loop=self.setInterval(function(){
          if(jen.map) {
              //execute code here after jen.map is defined
              console.log(typeof jen.map);
              window.clearInterval(loop);
          }
      },50);
```

Check jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9yv5t/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the [docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/layer-amd.html) and it seems that there are various events you could listen to.

For example:

```
var m = new Map(...);

m.on('load', function () {
    //execute code when the first layer is ready
});

var l = new Layer(...);

l.on('load', function () {
    //execute code when the layer has been initialized
});
```

It's also carefully stated for the [Layer.load](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/layer-amd.html#load) event:

> fires after layer properties for the layer are successfully populated.
>   This event must be successful before the layer can be added to the
>   map.

Comment: I'll keep messing with that I tried the load event but it wasn't working, its probably an issue with my execution. Thanks for pointing that out though

Comment: @atlMapper Could you show what you are doing in `addNewLayer`?